# loading list of strings from sharedpreference and display it as list of textView

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I have designed my activity `xml` as given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#C0C0C0"
        android:layout_weight="10">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/wall"
            android:background="#C0C0C0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="90"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:shadowColor="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/post"
            android:background="@drawable/post"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now in this activity on pressing imagebutton i'am adding a textview to the layout everytime. i want to load all textViews created yet on launching this activity. do i need to run loop on arraylist which i got from sharedpreference, to create all textviews created yet? or there is something else which i can use because i think creating list of all textviews on launching activity through loop will take time.

Comment: You can loop through the array of strings and create `TextView`s dynamically and add them to the layout using `addView()` function.

Comment: ok yeah i thought about it.. but my question is won't it take time? or it will create in a moment? if list of strings is much long.

Comment: It depends on the number of records. More the number of records, the more time it takes. You can do a trial by yourself. I guess few hundreds should not take much time.

Comment: any other method is there which is more quiker than loop?